# Split string on comma following a specific word

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector with names, e.g.:

```
names <- "Jansen, A., Karel, A., Jong, A. de, Pietersen, K."
```

And I want to split this per name. In this case, I need to split the vector on `.,` and the comma following `de` (That name would be `A. De Jong`, which is typical in Dutch).

Right now I do:

```
 strsplit(names,split="\\.\\,|\\<de\\>,")
```

But this also removes the `de` from the name:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Jansen, A"      " Karel, A"      " Jong, A. "     " Pietersen, K."
```

How can I obtain the following as result?

```
[[1]]
[1] "Jansen, A"      " Karel, A"      " Jong, A. de"     " Pietersen, K."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

polishchuk's regex needs two modifications to make it work in R.

Firstly, the backslash needs escaping.  Secondly, the call to `strsplit` needs the argument `perl = TRUE` to enable lookbehind.

```
strsplit(names, split = "\\.,|(?<=de)", perl = TRUE)
```

gives the answer Sacha asked for.

Notice though that this still includes a dot in de Jong's name, and it isn't extensible to alternatives like van, der, etc.  I suggest the following alternative.

```
names <- "Jansen, A., Karel, A., Jong, A. de, Pietersen, K., Helsing, A. van"
#split on every comma
first_last <- strsplit(names, split = ",")[[1]]
#rearrange into a matrix with the first column representing last names, 
#and the second column representing initials
first_last <- matrix(first_last, byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2) 
#clean up: remove leading spaces and dots
first_last <- gsub("^ ", "", first_last)
first_last <- gsub("\\.", "", first_last)
#combine columns again
apply(first_last, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")
```

Comment: I should have known, help for `regular expressions` (in R) is implicit that lookaround is "a perl thing". Lookarounds are described under the section `Perl-like Regular Expressions`. Things are best hidden in plain view. :)

Comment: I only changed it to `\\.,|(?<= de),` to avoid names containing `de` breaking it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex: `\.,|(?<=de),` with look-behind.

It will match:

Jansen, A`.,` Karel, A`.,` Jong, A. de`,` Pietersen, K.

Comment: I tried looking behind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but I get an error saying it's not a valid regular expression.

Comment: I think you need to escape the round brackets. In R, this would look like `strsplit(names, split = "\\.,|\\(?<=de\\)")`.

Comment: I also tested it on regex pal and it complained. http://regexpal.com/ Notice that if you escape the brackets `\.,|\(?<=de\),`, it goes through.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, I only produce regex, how to escape character in your language I don't know. In C# it should be: `@"\.,|(?<=de),"`, i.e. without escaping.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, I think you don't need to escape `()` because it is part of expression.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The closest I got was by using square brackets and escaping, `\\.\\,|[?<=de],` but that only keeps `d` and not `de`.

Comment: @Sacha Epskamp, Try this: `\\.,|(?<=de),`. Don't escape `()` because it is look behind group.

Comment: @Sacha Epskamp, BTW I think your regex engine doesn't support look behind/ahead.

Comment: @Roman You mean `\\.,|\\(?<=de\\),` ? Doesn't work for me. `\\.,|(?<=de),` gives an "invalid regexp" error, I guess that's an R thing.

Comment: @Sacha Epskamp, I have no idea does R support this.

Comment: Gah, I messed up something and I thought it worked. Stand by. :)

Comment: @Sacha Epskamp, Wearisome minutes... :-)

Comment: @Sacha, polishchuk: R runs two different regex engines.  You need to set `perl = TRUE` to enable lookbehind.  See my answer.

Comment: @Richie, I don't use R. I only trying help OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out a really easy workaround for this problem which I am posting here for reference. Simply `gsub` the string first to something else that is easier to split:

```
names <- "Jansen, A., Karel, A., Jong, A. de, Pietersen, K."

names <- gsub("\\<de\\>,","de.,",names)
strsplit(names,split="\\.\\,")
[[1]]
[1] "Jansen, A"      " Karel, A"      " Jong, A. de"   " Pietersen, K."
```

I guess this requires a seperate `gsub()` statement for each way this can occur (in Dutch you have van, der, de, te, ten, and more), so it isn't ideal, but gets the job done.